# Textures occasionally rendering twice on a particular face

Tags: 3d, textures, webgl

I am learning how to render 3D objects using webgl (no third-party libraries).

I am currently facing a very confusing situation however, where my textures are rendering apparently twice over a particular triangle, but only on some of the triangles.

I have added a screenshot of the problem, and was rather hoping some gl-ninja in here would be able to point me in the direction of my mistake:

[image]

As you can see, most of the textures are rendering fine, the cobble stones and most of the triangles of the crates, I hope it is clear enough, in the top-right triangle of the bottom left crate the system is showing 2 textures (1 incorrect, quite strong, the other correct, quite weak).

I don't really expect you to wave a wand and fix this (though that would be nice!) I'm just hoping that you recognise the symptoms and can point me in the right direction, either terms to use in Google, or areas in my code that I should give some more thorough scrutiny.

UPDATE:
I'm so thankful for your help!

Somehow my object had set itself to render as a trianglestrip, instead of a triangle list. I realise there's no way you could have seen that, just leaving this here in case some fellow coder is stuck on the same strange issue!

Been looking into this for days now... live and learn!

Comment: Looks like your magic wand is changing the texture coordinates for your cubes. You just need to make sure you're adding the texture coordinates in the correct order and you'll be good to go. You have your vertices like this: http://www.developer.com/imagesvr_ce/5260/togl_3.jpg and your texture coordinates defined like: http://www.learnopengles.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/texture-coordinates-300x300.png

Comment: It looks like [Z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), as if you're accidentally rendering two copies of the cube at (almost) the same position, but with different UVs.

Comment: Ah yes, after looking at the larger image I think there's Z-fighting there as well. I think you're experiencing both issues.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.